# Generate random Numbers in Ascending order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, random

How to generate random numbers in ascending order like this in a loop and append them into a list

12345
12346
12347
12348.....

tried this, this code will generate random integer, Need them in ascending order.

```
lists = []
for z in range(3000):
    lists.append((randint(12345,13333)))

lists_1=[str(cell) for  cell in lists_phone]
print(lists_1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just generate the integers then sort them. In Python, `sort()` sorts a list:

```
listvar = [randint(12345,13333) for _ in range(3000)]
listvar.sort()
print(listvar)
```

Comment: Two caveats: 1. Calling a variable `list` will overwrite the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) (BTW, giving a `set` the name `list` is not the best of ideas). 2. After creating a set the number of entries might be reduced due to the elimination of duplicates.

Comment: @Matthias: I edited my answer, especially the second part which was added by the question asker, to address your comments.  See the edit history.

Comment: Thank you for the change. This might prevent us from questions like "list doesn't work anymore" later.

Answer (score 0):

If you must generate them one by one and they must be already in order:

```
lists = []
min = 12345
max = 13333
for z in range(3000):
    lists.append(max * z + (randint(min,max)))

lists_1=[str(cell) for  cell in lists_phone]
print(lists_1)
```

But probably what you are really looking for is @Peter O. answer.

Answer (score 0):

numpy's version to @Peter O's approach. If you already have numpy you can use it for a much better performance:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import Timer
from random import randint

print(min(Timer(lambda: [randint(12345, 13333) for _ in range(3000)].sort()).repeat(100, 100)))
print(min(Timer(lambda: np.random.randint(12345, 13333, 3000).sort()).repeat(100, 100)))
```

Outputs

```
0.5073430000000023
0.016132899999999673
```

Numpy is 31 times faster